# Creating Stored Procedures that can work with different tables

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, view

I need to use the same Stored Procedures against many tables all with the same structure in my DB. This is data loaded from customers,with one table/customer and the data needs calculations/checks run before it's loaded to our DataWarehouse.

So far these are the options and issues I've found and I'm looking for a better pattern/approach.

1. Create a view that points to the
   table I want to process, the SPs
   then talk to that view. This works
   well (especially once I'd worked out
   how to create views 'automagically'
   based on their columns). But the
   view can only be used with one table
   at a time, forcing the system to
   deal with one customer at a time.
2. Use dynamic sql within each SP -
       makes the SPs much harder to
       read/debug and for those reasons has
       been ruled out
3. Create a partitioned view across
       all the tables and then use a
       paramatised table function to return
       just the data we're interested in -
       ah but then I can't update the data
       as the function returns a table that
       can be only used for select
4. Use dynamic sql inside a function
       (can't be done) to create a view
       (which also can't be done) .... give
       up
5. Within the SP create a temp table
       with over the target table using
       dynamic sql, but then the temp table
       only exists in the session that runs
       the dynamic sql not the 'parent'
       session that's running the SP ...
       give up
6. Create a global temp table using
       dynamic SQL to avoid the scope issue
       of 5, then run the SP against the
       global temp table. Still run into
       the single customer issue.
7. Create the view as in 1 within a
       transaction and then run all the SPs
       and then commit - works fine for one
       user, but any others are now blocked
       trying to create a new view of the
       same name
8. Use a temporary view ... can't in
       T/Sql
9. Move all the code into .Net - but
       we have environment issues where
       tsql is much easier to host/run

I know I'm not the only person who has this problem, have any of you good people solved it, please help.

Comment: Well, MrTelly, you have only accepted answers for half of the 50 questions you have asked here so far, so my level of interest in continuing to try to help you is pretty low.

Comment: Do you need to check the whole data in each table or just some rows? Is the process runned in more tha one instance at the time? If so, the batch will process the same tables/rows?

Comment: I understand your point of view, @MrTelly. But understand, please, that people who are trying to build their reputation might pause at spending a considerable amount of time and thought over studying and responding to a fairly challenging question like yours when the probability of being rewarded for their efforts appears to be so low. Even with a bounty now, what are the chances you will award it? I am just trying to help you get your head around the reality here.

Comment: Hi Dok, which of the three answers (so far) would you choose? It appears that no-one has solved this problem well, or if they have they're not prepared to share.

Comment: -1 for ruling out most options. Do you want this solved or not?

Comment: @MrTelly: please provide some additional details on your environment explaining why .NET is unfeasible.

Comment: @gbn of course I want it solved, this has been an ongoing issue for months, hence trying many things - that do not work. There are two approaches that do work - .Net and Dynamic Sql that. I've ruled them out for the following reasons. Dynamic sql is awful to support and write, we're talking about thousands of lines of sql code here, and the ongoing support/maintenance of this system is important.

Comment: .Net is not great in our environment as we want to run the code on the server but we're not allowed to A) Deploy an Assembly into the Server, B) Deploy code onto the Sql machine - both restrictions are part of the agreement we have with our service provider.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe your approach is wrong, I will go deep in details in a while but it seems that your problem can be solved using SSIS

-- **Updated answer**:

First, the big picture:

The most affordable way to process the tables dynamically is using a script instead of a stored procedure. If you want to make table access randomly chosen, you certainly will not use any of the performance advantages of stored procedures, i.e. execution plans. A SQL Script can be easily upgraded to point one table at runtime using placeholders and replacing it before executing.

The script can be loaded from the filesystem, a variable, a text column in a table, etc. The loading process consists in read the script content to a string variable. This step occurs once.

The next step is the preparation stage. This step will be executed for each table to be processed. The main business of this step is to replace the table placeholders with the current table being processed. Also is possible to set parameter values like any parameter you can need to pass into the sp that you already wrote.

The last step is the execution of the script. As is already loaded into a variable and the placeholders were set to the current table name, you can safely call a ExecuteSQLTask with the sql variable as the input. This process of course happens for each table you want to process.

Ok. Now let's see this in action.

This is a sample database model:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[t_n](
  [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
  [start] [datetime] NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_t_n] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

where t_n represents any table (t_1, t_2, t_3, etc).

This is your current stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SpProcessT_n 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT * FROM [t1]; 
END
GO
```

Now, transform this stored procedure to a Sql script, placing a placeholder instead of the table name

```
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT * FROM [$table_name];
```

I choose to save this in a .sql file in the filesystem to keep the POC as simple as possible.

Next, create a SSIS Package like this:

[image: Basic SSIS Package]

These are the settings I choose to set up the loop:
[image]

And this is the way you can assign the table name to a variable called appropriately _table_name_
[image]

This is the setup of the script task, here you find that the variable _table_name_ has read only access, while a new variable called SqlExec has read/write access:

[image]

And this is it's Main function:

```
    public void Main()
    {
        String Table_Name = Dts.Variables["table_name"].Value.ToString();
        String SqlScript;
        Regex reg = new Regex(@"\$table_name", RegexOptions.Compiled);
        using (var f = File.OpenText(@"c:\sqlscript.sql")) {
            SqlScript = f.ReadToEnd();
            f.Close();
        }
        SqlScript = reg.Replace(SqlScript, Table_Name);
        Dts.Variables["SqlExec"].Value = SqlScript;
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

You can notice that the Dts Variable SqlExec contains the sql script that will be executed. Now you can set the following options in your ExecuteSqlTask:

[image]

Successfully tested in MSSQL 2008, if you put a insert inside the script file you will notice new rows in each table.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm intrigued can you fill out your answer so I know what the approach is

Answer (score 2):

If your application can afford to have one cut-off day late, then you can have a nightly scheduled job to run an SSIS package that will consolidate all 150+ tables into one single huge table. Since the freshness of the results of the queries against that huge table will then be 1 'date' late, this solution will not include any rows that recently been loaded.

You can actually time the running of this package. If it is still amazingly fast, say within 30 minutes, then you can bet to run it in every few hours, like during: the start of work day, lunch break, and end of day. This way you can have a nearly fresh data to query with.

Comment: You can use this SSIS tool to do row checksum. So, instead destroying and rebuilding the huge data over again each time, only different rows will get updated, http://www.sqlis.com/sqlis/post/Checksum-Transformation.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

Write a partitioned view including table names?

```
SELECT 'TableName', t.* FROM TableName t
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'TableName2', t.* FROM TableName2 t
```

Then write a single instead of trigger which uses dynamic SQL for writing (less testing involved with that use of dynamic SQL because you'd just write the simple CRUD operations once for all tables I'd think)

Comment: I can mimic that approach with a partitioned view and a where clause but it's horribly inefficient when I have 120+ tables and know that I'm only updating one of them

Comment: Ah yes, I wasn't remembering that T-SQL won't optimize that if the value is a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I would not do this with SQL.  What you are describing sounds like a traditional [ETL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) situation.

Since all of the customer tables are the same, I would create a table in the data warehouse with all the columns from the client table, a surrogate key column, and a type identifier.  You have an option to create a "staging" table here that will only have data in it during the ETL process, or just working on a single "live" table.  I would create the staging table.

Then within SSIS package (don't worry you can still schedule from SQL Server agent, it hasn't totally left the DB server), start the ETL process...

**E**(xtract):  copy the data from your source into the staging table in the data warehouse.  You most likely want to use a sub-package within a foreach loop and changing the name of the table that you want to process from an external store (most people would say put this in the warehouse, but its up to you).

**T**(ransform): run the calculations/checks you were talking about, but do it on the whole set...

**L**(oad): Copy it to your real within the data warehouse.

There are a couple things I would NOT do. 
     1. Modify the data in the source table.
     2. Try to do this in t-sql. Its just not what tsql is good at.

If you need more detail on this approach, I would probably ask the question with some Business Intelligence tags.  I'll be traveling for the next week or so, but I will try to look at the comments to clear anything up if you need me to.

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly certain that the standard way to solve this is using dynamic SQL in each sp (your option 2), which has already been ruled out.

Your goal is to make generic, multi-table SQL. I don't see how you intend to accomplish that without sacrificing some efficiency and readability.